# How to earn the 'On a rail' achievement in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, achievements

I started a survival world where I would try to get every achievement possible.

I'm currently stuck on the achievement called "on a rail" I have placed 20 stacks of normal/power rail in 1 direction (east) I have not got the achievement for traveling 1km in a single direction, however when I check my stats it says I've traveled 10km?

What is needed to unlock this achievement?